# input/output error during read on /dev/sda/

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu, boot-repair

I have got myself stuck in a serious situation. There was problem booting my ubuntu after a hard shut-down. I used a live CD to run ubuntu. I installed boot-repair in it and ran it. To my surprise it not only removed my ubuntu but also my windows. Now I am not able to install ubuntu again because of this error. The report generated by boot-repair is in the provided link. 
Please help

[http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pvGwHrwDb4/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4sYl.png)
Here are the screenshots of the smart data window from disks utility of my ubuntu partition.
[image: Screenshot of ubuntu partition]
[image: First screen]
[image]

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` app, and get screenshot(s) of the SMART Data window.

Comment: @heynnema added screenshots

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. Is this a laptop or desktop computer? Other than possibly a loose cable, your disk looks like it is toast. You **could** try installing a new GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive) and see if you could reinstall OSs, but I don't hold out a lot of hope.

Comment: This is Hp Pavilion notebook so a laptop.

Comment: All partitions show up as unknown type. If nothing else, your GPT partition table is toasted. You **could** try a `gparted` repair, or a `testdisk` repair... and maybe you can backup any important stuff...

Comment: Only the live usb shows up in gparted and testdisk repair. No previously installed ubuntu drive is showing up in either of them.

Comment: Do you see the Ubuntu drive using the `Disks` app? It did before. How many drives do you have, and how are they attached?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `fsck`? It's a utility that checks consistencies in a file system and makes repairs. To run it you'll have to make sure the drive isn't mounted to avoid altering disk data and causing runtime errors. Boot from live DVD/USB and run `fsck /dev/sda3` on the drive from your terminal.

Comment: Running fsck gives

fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda3

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Comment: https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/